# I am getting problem while importing the csv file into oracle 12c, It showing an error severe error must be corrected

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

[enter image description here][1]

Above is the image of my error

Comment: There's no any content in your question. Please, edit it and provide error text in text format, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing data from SQL developer by using import wizard.
You can try following method:

1. Use SQL-Loader(It works when your database and CSV file are on different server or same server)
2. use external table for importing CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

1. external tables:
   https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/examples-using-oracle-external-tables.html#GUID-03CE63AD-F046-4805-A560-E4CFD7FA8503
2. sqlldr:
   https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144
3. other tools: sql developer, pl/sql developer, toad...